# Qt auto software version?

Tags: qt

Does Qt maintain any sort of versioning information about your program like .NET does? Like the build number? Or does it provide an easy way to access the SVN revision?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No.

But if you're using `qmake` then you can set compiler flags in the build system based on the results of arbitrary commands, which might be usable to do what you want.

For example, if you were using git, you could do something like this in your `.pro` file:

```
REVISION = $$system(git rev-parse HEAD)
DEFINES += APP_REVISION=$$REVISION
```

That would give you an `APP_REVISION` macro when compiling your program, which you could use like this:

```
// stringize macro
#define _STR(X) #X
#define STR(X) _STR(X)
QTextStream(cout) << "MyApp revision " STR(APP_REVISION) << endl;
```

Comment: Neat! I'll have to play around with this. I'm using NetBeans as my IDE and it builds the .pro file itself, so I have to figure out how to get it to *not* overwrite my changes.

Comment: If you do `DEFINES += APP_REVISION=\\\"$$REVISION\\\"` in your project file, then you don't need to pollute your source files with the `STR` macro.

Comment: @Dan: this is true, however the problem is that the number of backslashes required in your example is platform-specific (even shell-specific, as mingw32-make.exe on windows may run commands via cmd or via sh depending on environment).  I think it's quite hard to get it right.